# Tensorflow Documentation

Tags: tensorflow

I am increasingly irritated and frustrated by the `Tensorflow` documentation. I searched on google for documentation regarding

```
tf.reshape
```

I'm getting directed to a generic page like [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html). I want to see the details of `tf.reshape` and not the entirety of the documentation.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: have the same issue, an alternative would be to search the repository and read the documentation and tests from there https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=reshape

Comment: Just opened an issue on github. <https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4021>

Comment: For other people just now stumbling upon this, it is worth adding that the link provided in the question contains another link named tf.reshape that takes the user to the actual tf.reshape documentation.

Comment: a google search for items like 'tf.shape' now lists the appropriate page at the top of the search results.

Answer (score 32):

Do not Google about Tensorflow documentation, use the [TensorFlow Python reference documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/index.html) and `ctrl` + `f`

Comment: This is what I currently use, but I guess it would be better if Google search would redirect you to the specific page.

Comment: Maybe. But what Google index is not Tebsorflow related or, by the way, is better to open an issue on Tebsorflow's GitHub page to ask for a better design of the documentation in order to achieve better indexing

Comment: Thanks a lot for all these hints and solutions. But it still would make sense that you can standard google what you need. I do this with pretty everything I do like python commands or sklearn methods etc. And, TF  comes from Google like the search? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The probably fastest way is to use the Tf documentation is:
http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/

Just type `tf.reshape` and you are done.
which can be also used offline and automatically updates the docs.

**edit:** even typing only `res` shows you the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Update for posterity:
With the new TensorFlow, the website is now indexed with Google, and it should also soon be indexed by other search engines.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you use the GitHub repo as your documentation instead.  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes

For example `tf.reshape` is in a single Markdown file https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard0/tf.reshape.md

To search for the document you want, you could use the GitHub search under that `functions_and_classes` folder.

An example is

`tf.reshape() path:tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes language:Markdown`

[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=✓&q=tf.reshape%28%29+path%3Atensorflow%2Fg3doc%2Fapi_docs%2Fpython%2Ffunctions_and_classes+language%3AMarkdown&type=Code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tf.reshape%28%29%20path%3Atensorflow%2Fg3doc%2Fapi_docs%2Fpython%2Ffunctions_and_classes%20language%3AMarkdown&type=Code)

which search for `tf.reshape()` under the documentation folder.

Answer (score 2):

I use the non-official [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash)/[Zeal](https://zealdocs.org/) docset for TensorFlow:

https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/dash-docset-tensorflow

It is a very convenient way of browsing the TensorFlow documentation offline and it solves the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) what you are looking for? Using the search functionality of the browser helped me find it.

Comment: i think he wanted google to take him directly to that anchor, but it doesn't

Comment: Thanks, yes, this could do the job actually.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have installed tensorflow in your computer and that you know the name of function that you may want to use.

So if you use some Python IDE, I think you can directly jump to the declaration or definition of this function and see the usage and explanation. That is the same documentation as online (although for some functions it is not very clear).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the url for tensorflow documentation and add what you want to search..

The base url is: 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/

You can add `what_ever_you_want_to_search` after the /

Answer (score 1):

Since Tensorflow r1.1 **a search on google for items like 'tf.shape' now lists the appropriate page** at the top of the search results.

This didn't work back in r0.10 and r0.11, maybe because there were many markdown formatting issues in the Tensorflow docs themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tf is developing best way is to go through the tf API. And it's good if you can follow these slides in **http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs20si/**